# 'http://localhost:8888/mydomain/path' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is present

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, cors

My angular web application hosted at http://localhost:4200 makes a request http://localhost:8888/mydomain/path
for my spring boot java backend as described below:

Angular frond-end:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT');
this.http.get('http://localhost:8888/mydomain/path', { headers: headers })
    .subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

Searching the internet I found a setting to solve the cors origin problem in the java/spring boot backend

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfigurations extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/*").permitAll()
            .and().csrf().disable().cors().disable();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("corsFilter")
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
    

}
```

But the get call is returning the below error. What would be the problem? What am I forgetting to do or doing wrong? ?Thanks a lot

```
'http://localhost:8888/mydomain/path' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution described by @j1s solved my problem, I just had to make small changes to make it work in my case.
I will describe below:

I created the proxy.config.json file in the root of my project

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8888",
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/api": "/mydomain"
          },
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "info"
    }
}
```

I added the configuration in angular.json

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "myapp:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "myapp:build:development",
              "proxyConfig": "proxy.config.json"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
```

And finally my call to api needed to be

```
http://localhost:4200/api/path
```

That way everything worked perfectly fine.
Thanks to @j1s for the solution!

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to give as array

```
configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
```

Answer (score -1):

There might be some problem in the configuration in ur cors setting in the server.

There is a better solution to use the PROXY in Angular to overcome CORS.

1. Add a proxy.config.js file in the root folder.

[image]

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/api"
    ],
    target: "http://localhost:8888",
    secure: false,
    logLevel: "debug",
    changeOrigin: true
  }
];

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

2. Add `"proxyConfig": "proxy.config.js"` in the angular.json file under the serve: So when u run ng serve the poxy will be added to the angular node lite server.
   [image]
3. In your api call you have to call the api as `http://localhost:4200/api/mydomain/path` so from the browser it will be calling the apis in 4200, so the CORS err cannot come as now its calling the same domain.
   In the node lite server it will change the url to `http://localhost:8888/mydomain/path` and call the api as a server to server call. You can see the 'api' in the URL will be cut off by the proxy server and change the target as provided in the config.

Comment: I followed all the steps and implemented the suggested code snippets. in angular.json "serve": { "configurations": { "development": { "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.config.js" ... But error message HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404 , statusText: 'Not Found', url: 'http://localhost:4200/api/mydomain/path'

Comment: It needs to be under the options see the line no 82, and make sure ur proxy.cofig.js in the right path.. And in the console, you should see the logs printing the proxy calls.

Comment: I had to make some changes to get it working here. I changed proxy.config to json format and added pathRewrite property. It looked like this {"/api": {"target": "http://localhost:8888", "pathRewrite": {"^/api": "/mydomain"}, "secure": false, "logLevel" : "info"}}. I needed the proxy in serve/configurations/development in angular.json. In my api the call is being made like this http://localhost:4200/api/path. That way everything worked perfectly well!!! Thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

<s>create a `@Component` bean implementing `WebMvcConfigurer`:</s>

**update**

According to [this link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors#1-javaconfig) the annotations should be the ones bellow:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CoreWebMvcConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", "Origin", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "Authorization")
                .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS");
    }
}
```

i hope it works this time

**update 2**

this sample repository using [this branch](https://github.com/sombriks/exercicio-spring-angular/tree/config-alternativa-cors/backend/src/main/java/exercicio/java/angular/backend) actually works fine using `WebMvcConfigurer` approach.

Comment: I added this bean, but still the same problem

Comment: @araraujo i've fixed the annotations, let me know if it woks this time.

Comment: unfortunately the same error continues after these fixes

Comment: @araraujo please check the project branch i've put in the updated answer. classpath scan is suppoed to find configuration beans.

can you set up a sample project dermonstrating your current issue?